# Datewise split for start and end date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I a beginner in sql. I want to split my date fields as follows.
Please help me out.

**input:**

```
Id  Start_date  End_date
1   12/7/2018 22:00:34  13/7/2018 1:24:22
```

**output:**

```
Id     Start_date   End_date
1   12/7/2018 22:00:34  12/7/2018 23:59:59
1   13/7/2018 00:00:00  13/7/2018 1:24:22
```

Comment: What DBMS are you actually using? Date/time functions/operators are quite product specific.

Comment: I'm using Amazon redshift.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a UNION since you know you'll end up with two records for each one input record. Then just monkey with your timestamps to get this output:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (id int, start_date timestamp(0), end_date timestamp(0));

INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (1, '2018-07-12 22:00:34'::TIMESTAMP, '2018-07-13 01:24:22'::TIMESTAMP);

SELECT * FROM testtable;

 id |     start_date      |      end_date
----+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | 2018-07-12 22:00:34 | 2018-07-13 01:24:22

SELECT id, start_date, (start_date::date + 1) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS end_date FROM testtable
UNION ALL
SELECT id, end_date::date, end_date FROM testtable;

 id |     start_date      |      end_date
----+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | 2018-07-12 22:00:34 | 2018-07-12 23:59:59
  1 | 2018-07-13 00:00:00 | 2018-07-13 01:24:22
```

This will break down if more than two records are desired. I'm suspecting now that I read through this that you might have an interval of a few days, in which case you might want `00:00:00` to `23:59:59` for each full date in that interval...?

Comment: Thanks for the update. But the above can give us false data when the start date and end date falls on the same dates. I have given the scenerio below         
Input:    
    
1 7/12/2018 15:52:00 7/12/2018 17:57:46  
2 7/11/2018 7:00:16 7/12/2018 15:51:54  
3 7/12/2018 17:58:10 7/12/2018 18:01:15  
    
Output:    
    
2 7/11/2018 7:00:16 7/11/2018 23:59:59  
2 7/12/2018 0:00:00 7/12/2018 15:51:54  
3 7/12/2018 17:58:10 7/12/2018 23:59:59  
3 7/12/2018 0:00:00 7/12/2018 19:49:55  
1 7/12/2018 15:52:00 7/12/2018 23:59:59  
1 7/12/2018 0:00:00 7/12/2018 17:57:46

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. But the above can give us false data when the start date and end date falls on the same dates. I have given the scenerio below

**Input:**

1   7/12/2018 15:52:00  7/12/2018 17:57:46
2   7/11/2018 7:00:16   7/12/2018 15:51:54
3   7/12/2018 17:58:10  7/12/2018 18:01:15

**Output:**

2   7/11/2018 7:00:16   7/11/2018 23:59:59
2   7/12/2018 0:00:00   7/12/2018 15:51:54
3   7/12/2018 17:58:10  7/12/2018 23:59:59
3   7/12/2018 0:00:00   7/12/2018 19:49:55
1   7/12/2018 15:52:00  7/12/2018 23:59:59
1   7/12/2018 0:00:00   7/12/2018 17:57:46

Comment: Please add this to an edit on the question. I have a solution that works well in version of Postgres that are newer than 5 years ago, but Redshift still doesn't support generate_series for timestamps so a workaround would be needed to make it redshift friendly